# Möbius transformation composition

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Suppose we have

$F(z)=f(\phi(z))$ where $\phi$ is a Möbius transformation which maps points of the unit circle to points of the unit circle. Suppose also that there is an interval of length $\pi$ such that on that interval $f(e^{it})-f(e^{-it})>0$. How to prove then this is also true for $F$?

Here, I defined:

$\phi(z):=\frac{z_0-z}{1-\bar{z_0}z}$ with $z_0$ a fixed point of the unit disk (without the boundary) and $f$ a real harmonic continuous function defined on the unit disk. And $F(z)=f(\phi(z))$.

Anyone an idea please?

Comment: That depends on the metric you are using. It is true for the so called Poincaré half plane. See, e.g., here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031850/prove-a-matrix-in-sl2-bbb-r-representing-a-m%C3%B6bius-transformation-is-an-isom

Comment: Thank you. I think in euclidian distance it is not true because a rescaling is also mobius.

Comment: @anonymous123 I think the statements you've read on the internet were in the context of the metric I have defined in my answer. Please check it and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: The assertion you are trying to prove is simply false.

Answer (score 5):

The statement is true if you use the *"right"* notion of distance.

Consider the upper half plane $\mathbb H := \{z\in \Bbb C: \operatorname{Im} z > 0\}$. For two points $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb H$ with $z_k = x_k + iy_k$ (for $k=1,2$), the hyperbolic distance $d(z_1,z_2)$ between them is defined as the infimum of $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}}{y}\, dt$$
taken over all paths $\gamma(t)$ with $\gamma(t_k) = z_k = x(t_k) + iy(t_k)$ for $k=1,2$.

Then, the following theorem holds.

> **Theorem.** Möbius transformations with coefficients in $\Bbb R$ preserve hyperbolic lengths, i.e., if $\phi(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ for $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb R$ and $z_1,z_2 \in \Bbb H$, then $d(z_1,z_2) = d(\phi(z_1), \phi(z_2))$.

For a proof, see [these notes.](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Chang.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Möbius transformations preserve angles, not distances.  That's called a conformal map. The Möbius transformations are the conformal automorphisms of the Riemann sphere (extended complex plane.)  They map circles on the Riemann sphere to circles on the Riemann sphere.  So viewed on the complex plane, they map a circle or line to a circle or line.  For instance, the Cayley transform $\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ maps the real line bijectively to the unit circle. Obviously, the Euclidean distance is **not** preserved.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question now because if this statement is not true, I don't know how to prove the fact I mentioned in my edited question.

Comment: Your modified question doesn't have enough information.  For instance, if $\phi$ is a Möbius transformation with real coefficients and positive determinant - then $\phi$ maps a pair of conjugate complex numbers to a pair of conjugate complex numbers in the same vertical order.  So that gives the conclusion you're looking for.  Otherwise I don't see why it's true without more information about either $f$ or $\phi$.

Comment: $\phi(z):=\frac{z_0-z}{1-\bar{z_0}z}$ with $z_0$ a fixed point of the unit disk (without the boundary) and $f$ a real harmonic continuous function defined on the unit disk. And $F(z)=f(\phi(z))$. But I don't understand why I have the conclusion I'm looking for then? @John Doe